# Global variable handling

Tags: php, error-handling, global-variables

While I'm trying to handle WARNING messages, I'm getting error for global variable/array (on last print_r line):

> Notice:  Undefined variable: errors in........

I tried to declare **$errors** outside of function as well but same problem.

Thanks

**My code:**

```
set_error_handler('validation_error_handler', E_WARNING);

function validation_error_handler($error_no, $error_message)
{
    global $errors;
    $errors[] = $error_message;
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($errors); echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `$errors` as an array first:

```
set_error_handler('validation_error_handler', E_WARNING);
$errors = array(); // Add this...
```

**Update:**

```
set_error_handler('validation_error_handler', E_WARNING);

$errors = array();

function validation_error_handler($error_no, $error_message)
{
    global $errors;
    $errors[] = $error_message;
}

echo preg_match();

echo '<pre>'; print_r($errors); echo '</pre>';
```

This will print

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => preg_match() expects at least 2 parameters, 0 given
)
</pre>
```

Make sure your error/warning occurs before you `print_r($errors);`

Comment: I did. The array should have 2 warning errors stored in it. Deliberately by done by myself but doesn't echo anything. Array looks empty.

Comment: updated answer. Sounds like you might be trying to print_r errors before they occur.. Example above works. I called preg_match without any attribs.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `$errors` outside of your function then pass it by reference into your function.

```
$errors = array();

function validation_error_handler($error_no, $error_message, &$errors)
{
    $errors[] = $error_message;
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($errors); echo '</pre>';
```

Avoid using global variables in this fashion, as they can cause conflicts if included in other files.

Also, read up on variable scope in php: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php